# jq: Conditional insert using "lookup" & "target" JSON objects

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to improve a bash script I wrote using `jq` (Python version), but can't quite get the conditional nature of the task at hand to work.

**The task**: insert array from one JSON object ("lookup") into another ("target") *only* if the key of the "lookup" matches a particular "higher-level" value in the "target". Assume that the two JSON objects are in `lookup.json` and `target.json`, respectively.

A minimal example to make this clearer:

"Lookup" JSON:

```json
{
   "table_one": [
      "a_col_1",
      "a_col_2"
   ],
   "table_two": [
      "b_col_1",
      "b_col_2",
      "b_col_3"
   ]
}
```

"Target" JSON:

```json
{
  "top_level": [
    {
      "name": "table_one",
      "tests": [
        {
          "test_1": {
            "param_1": "some_param"
          }
        },
        {
          "test_2": {
            "param_1": "another_param"
          }
        }]
    },
    {
      "name": "table_two",
      "tests": [
        {
          "test_1": {
            "param_1": "some_param"
          }
        },
        {
          "test_2": {
            "param_1": "another_param"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the output to be:

```json
{
    "top_level": [{
                "name": "table_one",
                "tests": [{
                        "test_1": {
                            "param_1": "some_param"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "test_2": {
                            "param_1": "another_param",
                            "param_2": [
                                "a_col_1",
                                "a_col_2"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "table_two",
                        "tests": [{
                                "test_1": {
                                    "param_1": "some_param"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "test_2": {
                                    "param_1": "another_param",
                                    "param_2": [
                                        "b_col_1",
                                        "b_col_2",
                                        "b_col_3"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Hopefully, that makes sense. Early attempts slurped both JSON blobs and assigned them to two variables. I'm trying to select for a match on [roughly] `($lookup | keys[]) == $target.top_level.name`, but I can't quite get this match or the subsequent the array insert working.

Any advice is well-received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JSON samples have been corrected, and that the following program is in the file "target.jq", the invocation:

```
jq --argfile lookup lookup.json -f target.jq target.json
```

produces the expected result.

### target.jq

```
.top_level |= map(
  $lookup[.name] as $value
  | .tests |= map(
      if has("test_2")
      then .test_2.param_2 = $value
      else . end) )
```

### Caveat

Since `--argfile` is officially deprecated, you might wish to choose an alternative method of passing in the contents of lookup.json, but `--argfile` is supported by all extant versions of jq as of this writing.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @peak. Let me try to implement this. As for passing in the contents of `lookup.json`, could I not just pass in both files and assign to variables to handle accordingly: `jq -s '.[0] as $lookup | .[1] as $target | ...' lookup.json target.json`?

Comment: You could, but why bother?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking this would reduce the risk of `--argfile` deprecation coming to haunt me later on down the road.

Comment: Using -s can also cause trouble.

Comment: Yes, as I learned the hard way -- you cannot use your solution with `-s`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  With trivial adjustments, the solution as given will work regardless of how the contents of the two files are passed in.  `-s` can cause trouble because of its memory requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The ***jq*** answer is already given, but the ask itself is so fascinating - it requires a cross-lookup from a source file into the file being inserted, so I could not help providing also an alternative solution using **`jtc`** utility:

```
<target.json jtc -w'<name>l:<N>v[-1][tests][-1:][0]' \
                 -i file.json -i'<N>t:' -T'{"param_2":{{}}}'
```

A brief overlook of the used options:

- `-w'<name>l:<N>v[-1][tests][-1:][0]'` - selects *points of insertions* in the source (`target.json`) by finding and memorizing into namespace `N` keys to be looked up in the inserted file, then rolling back 1 level up in the JSON tree, selecting `tests` label, then the last entry in it and finally addressing a 1st element of the last one
- `-i file.json` make an insertion from the file
- `-i'<N>t:'` - this *walk* over `file.json` finds recursively a tag (label) preserved in the namespace `N` from the respective walk `-w` (if not this insert option with *the walk argument*, then the whole file would get inserted into the insertion points `-w..`)
- `-T'{"param_2":{{}}}'` - finally, a template operation is applied onto the insertion result transforming found entry (in `file.json`) into the one with the right label

PS. I'm the developer of the `jtc` - multithreading JSON processing utility for unix.
PPS. the disclaimer is required by SO.